# Regular Expression help in Ruby

Tags: ruby, regex

Can anybody help me write a regular expression which could find all the instances of the following in a long string >

`type="array" count="x" total="y"`

where x and y could be any numbers from 1 to 100.

language is ruby.

Comment: How important is the "1 to 100" bit? Must it not match numbers bigger than 100 at all?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, since we'll use the regex for a number twice, we'll save it as its own variable.  Note that the `number` regex is comprised of three separate pieces: one-digit numbers, two-digit numbers, and three-digit numbers.  This is a good rule of thumb to use when trying to make a regex to match a range of numbers.  It's easy to get it wrong otherwise (allowing strings like `"07"`).

Once you have the `number` regex, the rest is easy.

```
number = /[1-9]|[1-9][0-9]|100/
regex  = /type="array" count="#{number}" total="#{number}"/
string.scan(regex)
```

Comment: @Jeff_Terrell The problem with the `match` is that you will just get the match object and that match object will only contains the first match and not all of the occurrences.

Comment: BTW, why are you upvoting this answer as it is right now. At least test it before please!

Comment: Good point, NeX.  That wasn't what nEEbz asked for, was it?  I've updated my code above.  Thanks!

Comment: @Jeff_Terrell yup he was trying to "find all the instances". Looks much better now ;)

Comment: thanks; it works. can you tell me what exactly this notation do  `#{}`  ?

Comment: @nEEbz - That interpolates the expression into the regex.  The same style works with double-quoted strings.  So, for example, "sum is #{3+4}" is the same string as "sum is 7".

Comment: @nEEbz - Actually, I glossed over an important point.  If Ruby simply interpolated regexes into regexes character by character, we'd get into trouble with the alternation (`|`) in the `number` regex, and a string like `'type="array" count="1'` would match (or even just `'10'`).  Thankfully, when Ruby (v. 1.9.2, at least) interpolates the sub-regex, it also wraps the sub-regex in parenthesis like so `(?-mix:...)`, so alternation works as expected.

Comment: @Jeff - Your posts are helping me improve my weak regex skills :)

Answer (score 1):

This will return an array of matches

```
long_string.scan(/type="array" count="(?:[1-9]\d?|100)" total="(?:[1-9]\d?|100)")
```